Bug in Ubuntu Studio live USB lock screen and unable to file in Launchpad
although the default user has no password, it is impossible to get out of the lock screen which automatically appears after the display is switched off. Pressing enter on the lock screen with a blank password does not work.
I went to the Ubuntu Studio launchpad site and was told that bugs could not be filed. Therefore, I added a comment to an existing bug filed with Lubuntu for a similar issue (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/2000787/comments/20), but the desktop environments are different. I believe that it is highly inappropriate that bugs cannot be filed and this lock screen problem renders the computer unusable as the screensaver automatically locks the computer if I forget to shake the mouse or to change the power settings.
Screenshot of launchpad not accepting bugs

Does this answer your question? How to report a system bug

I suggest you read what appears to be a phone message; you didn't try to report a bug against a Ubuntu Studio package, but the Ubuntu Studio project itself (bugs are filed against packages and not Projects!)  File against the appropriate package related to screensaver (and its not xscreensaver as Lubuntu uses) using ubuntu-bug package on the machine where the issue occurred, login (to lop) & file report.  The Lubuntu is is different, involving a now EOL release & different programs.

@guiverc it is actually quite confusing how to report Ubuntu Studio bugs, since the launchpad says: If you want to file a Ubuntu Studio bug, please do so at http://launchpad.net/ubuntustudio, and then that page says: "Ubuntu Studio must be configured in order for Launchpad to forward bugs to the project's developers." I understand why OP is confused, because I'm confused as well.

ack... yeah from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/ReportingBugs  (search engine pointed me to) I was taken to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntustudio-project which is NOT a very useful page on launchpad.   A better link than what I've used as second needs to be substituted in (alas I can't think of one, at least not currently)    I'm heading to bed... but reported on #ubuntustudio so may get attention

Ok, so it seems that the link is actually still: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug/?no-redirect - and then you have to find the correct package.

@Artur Meinild, that's a much better link than the Project page(bug tab) ... wanna put it in?   (or want me to???)   It can always be changed if a better link is provided by a Ubuntu Studio team member.   (ie. I was thinking of Bugs concerning Ubuntu Studio are reported at the '''[[https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntustudio-project|Ubuntu Studio Launchpad Page]]'''. You will need to create an account in order to file bugs there. bit if that's where you were thinking..

@guiverc please do so, I'm not very familiar with editing on Launchpad.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/ReportingBugs  edited... Thanks @Artur Meinild, & customautosys for noticing & seeking assistance (even if not ideal location)

Why is Lubuntu tagged here?

I reported it under the only known bug report for this issue which is under Lubuntu, but it is not the same underlying issue because Ubuntu Studio is KDE. I don't know what package to report it under as I don't know if this is a bug in the KDE screensaver, or the password system, or something else. Further, I clicked a link to the Launchpad page and it immediately tells me the bug cannot be reported and there are no projects under which I can report the bug. I just hope to raise the issue so that it will also be fixed for other users and the support page recommended that I ask here.

I have been using Kubuntu for more than 10 years but don't really use this channel and it's my first time trying Ubuntu Studio. By the way, I just realised that the page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/ReportingBugs now seems to be down?

FYI: Erich took the page down (Erick is Ubuntu Studio lead, I mentioned page on IRC) as covered in his answer. I do see Ubuntu Studio as a Ubuntu system (I have affiliations with Lubuntu & other Ubuntu teams, but we're all one large Ubuntu family). Ubuntu Studio, Kubuntu, Ubuntu Desktop & all Ubuntu ISOs are built on the same infrastructure, from same repositories by same builder, just different seed files that dictate what is on the final ISO/installed. We have flavor sync meetings to keep us in sync, and all use Launchpad for bug tracking & required for fixes to be SRU'd (applied).

Your issue is already addressed in the Ubuntu Studio Release Notes. Ubuntu Studio does not support perpetually using the Live .iso image or using persistent drives. Therefore, there is no need to report a bug about this.
Furthermore, that link was for reporting bugs in Ubuntu Studio was taken down as it conflicts with the official documentation for reporting bugs in Ubuntu. Ubuntu Studio IS Ubuntu (not a weird derivitive that adds repositories) just like every official flavor, so having a separate way to report bugs is wrong.

Hi, the problem is not that I want to use it perpetually. I set it to install and then I went to the toilet or something and came back, hey presto the screen is locked and I have no way of telling whether the install completed successfully without any errors. So I had to waste time doing the whole install again just to be sure.

It's good that they know about the issue, I hope the goal is still to fix it (I perfectly understand this is an open source project so of course I'm not expecting or demanding that it be fixed immediately) rather than just to say "it's a bug just live with it".

We can't respin the .iso image. The only thing that might happen is we can fix it for the 24.04.1 image due in August. However, this is also a problem for Kubuntu which is using the same build logic and build system. We have to work with them and with the Ubuntu Release Team, who owns the build system, to do anything. This is far from a simple fix and has many moving parts and we don't have direct access to any of them.

Yeah sure, I totally understand that this sort of fix takes time. Thanks for taking the time to address it and I wish you and your team all the best with fixing this problem for 24.04.1 or future releases.
